# Can an Array be Added to Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Can An Array Be Added to Object? I have defined 2 Arrays itemId and itemName and pushed some values in them. Can these 2 arrays be pushed or be a part of ItemCatalog Object?

```
var ItemCatalog = new Object();

itemId = new Array();
itemName = new Array()

/*
var itemId = new Array();
var itemName = new Array();
*/
var currentItemIndex = 5;

itemId.push(1);
itemId.push(2);
itemId.push(3);
itemId.push(4);
itemId.push(5);
itemId.push(6);
itemId.push(7);
itemId.push(8);
itemId.push(9);
itemId.push(10);

itemName.push("A");
itemName.push("B");
itemName.push("C");
itemName.push("D");
itemName.push("E");
itemName.push("F");
itemName.push("G");
itemName.push("H");
itemName.push("I");
itemName.push("J");
```

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: ItemCatalog.Names = itemName;

Comment: These two arrays pushed where?

Comment: I recommend to read some JavaScript tutorial, especially [MDN - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
var itemId = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var itemName = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"];

var currentItemIndex = 5;

var ItemCatalog = {
    itemIds: itemId,
    itemNames: itemName
};
```

Another way to assign variables to your object would be:

```
var ItemCatalog = {}
// or like you did: var ItemCatalog = new Object(); That's the same as = {}

// Then:
ItemCatalog.itemIds = itemId;
// Or
ItemCatalog['itemNames'] = itemName;
```

Notice how I replaced your object / array initialisations with **[object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) / [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals) literals**. Both work, but I prefer the literals, since they're shorter.

Answer (score 1):

yes

```
var ItemCatalog = {
    itemId : itemId,
    itemName : itemName 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the arrays as values of properties of the object, like this:

```
// setup arrays here...

var itemCatalog = {
    itemId: itemId;
    itemNames: itemName
};
```

However if `id` and `name` are associated, why not add them in a single array? Something like this:

```
items = [];
items.push({ id: 1, name: 'A' });
items.push({ id: 2, name: 'B' });

console.log(items[0].name); // = A
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Continuing the code you've posted:

```
ItemCatalog.itemId = itemId;
ItemCatalog.itemName = itemName;
```

However, you can do this at the same time as creating the array, which saves cluttering up your current scope with an unnecessary variable:

```
var ItemCatalog = new Object();

ItemCatalog.itemId = new Array();
ItemCatalog.itemName = new Array();

ItemCatalog.itemId.push(1);
...

ItemCatalog.itemName.push("A");
...
```

Note also that by convention in JavaScript, names starting with a capital letter are used for constructor functions rather than objects. ([At least according to Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names).)

So this would be more idiomatic:

```
var itemCatalog = new Object();
```